# OpenFeign request throws AbstractMethodError

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, openfeign

Request:

```java
    @Headers("userId: {userId}")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/token")
    String getToken(@RequestHeader(name = "userId") Long userId);
```

Handler:

```java
    @GetMapping("/token")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getToken(@RequestHeader String userId) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        String token = jwtAuth.generateToken(userId);
        return ok(token);
    }
```

Exception:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringDecoder$FeignResponseAdapter does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode getStatusCode()' of interface org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I can post full stacktrace if needed

OpenFeign version is 3.1.5
Springboot 3

Comment: What versions are you using?

Comment: @spencergibb added version to the post

Comment: Spring Cloud openfeign 3.1.x is not compatible with spring boot 3. Look for a new release in the next week or so

Comment: Tried 3.0.x But still same issue.

Comment: Only 4.0.0 will work when it is released

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the spring-boot and spring-cloud versions are not aligned. For spring boot 3.X you can use spring cloud version **2022.0.x**.

Please note that this is different than the **OpenFeign version.**

```
<properties>
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

For more details, Please visit: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud.

Comment: After doing this I had to change my spring boot version to 3.0.x and spring-cloud-openfeign version to 4.0.1.
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/803#issuecomment-1346410680

Answer (score 1):

```
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Spring boot 3.X, 2022.0.X feign version should be used

Answer (score 1):

You need to use OpenFeign version 4.0.3 Springboot 3.x